# Force component to remount with new props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native@0.60.5` and `react-native-router-flux@4.0.6`. I'm trying to jump back from a `selectItems` component to a `newCollection`, which is a form.

I've created a component that renders a list of items with checkboxes. I use `setParams` to pass the selected items as props when a user hits the **Done** button — like so:

```
 // SelectItems.js
 this.props.navigation.setParams({
   rightTitle: 'Done',
   onRight: () =>
     Actions.jump('newCollection', {
       selectedItems: this.state.taggedItems,
     }),
 });
```

This works fine, and when the the`newCollection` component renders, I can show the list of selected items from `this.props.selectedItems` in my form.

I need to call an action creator using `this.props.selectedItems` when the component mounts.

Here's the action:

```
      // NewCollection.js

      // Map the items selected in the the `selectItems` component
      // and invoke an action

      var fetchTaggedItems = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.props.taggedItemsFetch(this.props.taggedItems.map(x => x.uid));
        resolve(this.props.matchingOutfits);
      });

      fetchTaggedItems.then(x => {
            console.log(x);
            alert('done!');
          });
```

Now, my understanding is that the component should remount when it receives these new props, but it won't. Using logs in `componentDidMount`, I see it only mounts on first entry.

I've tried the above code:

- Using `Actions.refresh()` instead of `Actions.jump()` — nothing happens
- Using `static onEnter()` to update the component state and force remount — can't access `this.state`
- Calling the action creator from within `render()` — infinite loop
- Setting a boolean `calledActionCreator` flag in state to prevent infinite loop — doesn't work
  — Comparing `this.props` with `prevProps` in `componentDidUpdate()` — Error: maximum update depth exceeded

I'm starting to think this is a bug with React Native Router Flux.

Comment: Please provide more information about your other components too

Comment: I've added code to show how I'm calling the action creator. Is there anything else that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

hope this code helps you, it was a part of my project that I need to force to update on props changes, in this code you can trigger what props changes and what it have to do. 
note: when you use setState, your components will render. in this lifeCycle, if a props Changes it call setState to reRender the component.

```
        if (this.props !== prevProps) {
            this.setState({
               // do somethings
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this in `componentDidUpdate()`, but I hit maximum update depth.

Comment: if you dont use it's ```if``` or  ```if``` statement is always true, it hits maximum update depth . @owiewio

Comment: Sorry, please could you clarify further? Do you mean if I don't include an `else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after much digging and experimentation, I've found a solution that works (at least on the surface).

Here goes:

```
// NewCollection.js
  static onEnter() {
    Actions.refresh({key: Math.random()});
  }
```

Using a plain `Actions.refresh()` to re-mount the component didn't seem to have any effect. Giving a random key as a prop seems to force an update.

I'm sure this isn't the most elegant solution, but it seems to work for now.